# Facebook app like button shows like count but insights doesn't show any

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-insights

I'm using the standard like button code on our Facebook app. This shows likes when you click it and increments as you would expect.

The page has all the correct meta data, app_id etc.

But in insights the 'likes' are always zero.

Anyone know if there is a setting I should look at or is this just another Facebook bug?